# Auto-Allocate to a specific RAM Area in GCC/C

Tags: c, gcc, ram, allocation

Sorry for my english, its a bit hard for me to explain what exactly i would need.
I'm making some extra code into existing binarys using the GCC compiler.
In this case, its PowerPC, but it should not really matter.

I know, where in the existing binary i have free ram available (i dumped the full RAM to make sure) but i need to define each RAM address manually, **currently i am doing it like this:**

```
// #ram.h

//8bit ram
uint8_t*        xx1     = (uint8_t*)    0x807F00;
uint8_t*        xx2     = (uint8_t*)    0x807F01;
//...and so on

// 16bit ram
uint16_t*       xxx1    = (uint16_t*)   0x807F40;
uint16_t*       xxx2    = (uint16_t*)   0x807F42;
//...and so on
    
// 32bit ram
uint32_t*       xxxx1   = (uint32_t*)   0x807FA0;
uint32_t*       xxxx2   = (uint32_t*)   0x807FA4;
//...and so on
```

**And im accessing my variables like this:**

```
void  __attribute__ ((noinline)) silly_demo_function() {
    #include "ram.h"
    
    if (*xxx2>*xx1) {
    *xxx3 = *xxx3 + *xx1; 
    }
    
return; 
}
```

But this gets really boring, if i want to patch my code into another existing binary, where the location of available/free/unused ram can be fully different, or if im replacing/removing some value in the middle. I am using 8, 16 and 32bit variables.

**Is there a way, i can define an area like 0x807F00 to 0x00808FFF, and allocate my variables on the fly, and the compiler will allocate it inside my specific location?**

Comment: okay, sorry, i will edit it, it was just easier to show it like this.

Comment: The question is not so clear. Are you running an embedded system? What is the OS? With multi-process OS the addresses are virtual and not physical/ram. So it's not clear what those addresses really represent and how it's possible that they map to ram.

Comment: There is no OS so far, the code im working on is written in C and compiled with something simular to GCC, the only thing i have here is raw binary and some explanaitions that's why i know where i need to work. Im adding new code into this binary (Its a ECU - engine control unit), and in this case its PowerPC architecture. Doing it like in my code example works fine, i know where i have free RAM, and i can read/write it doing it like in the example above. But i have a project which uses like 200 custom RAM addresses now, and its a mess if i have to change something in the middle.

Comment: And im accessing directly, so its a physical ram address, i have confirmed they are free and unused from the original code, but as bigger my code gets, as confusing it gets and im loosing a lot of available RAM because i dont even remember whats actually used and whats not if i change code.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area but I think it may help you to read up on [linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help me, i tried like everything i can try. But i cant get it to work. That why im hoping for someone here to know how to do it. PS: My whole project is built with linker scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile, i figured it out.

Its just as easy as defining .data, .bsss and .sbss in the linker directives.
6 Lines of code and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the big problem here is that those addresses are memory mapped IO (devices) and not RAM; and should not be treated as RAM.

Further, I'd say that you probably should be hiding the "devices that aren't RAM" behind an abstract layer, a little bit like a device driver; partly so that you can make sure that the compiler complies with any constraints caused by it being IO and not RAM (e.g. treated as `volatile`, possibly honoring any access size restrictions, possibly taking care of any cache coherency management); partly so that you/programmers know what is normal/fast/cached RAM and what isn't; partly so that you can replace the "device" with fake code for testing; and partly so that it's all kept in a single well defined area.

For example; you might have a header file called "src/devices.h" that contains:

```
#define xx1_address  0x807F00
```

..and the wrapper code might be a file called "src/devices/xx1.c" that contains something like:

```
#include "src/devices.h"


static volatile uint8_t * xx1  = (uint8_t*) xx1_address;


uint8_t get_xx1(void) {
    return *xx1;
}

void set_xx1(uint8_t x) {
    *xx1 = x;
}
```

However; depending on what these devices actually are, you might need/want some higher level code. For example, maybe `xx1` is a temperature sensor and it doesn't make any sense to try to set it, and you want it to scale that raw value so it's "degrees celsius", and the highest bit of the raw value is used to indicate an error condition (and the actual temperature is only 7 bits), so the wrapper might be more like:

```
#include "src/devices.h"

#define xx1_offset   -12.34
#define xx1_scale    1.234

static volatile uint8_t * xx1  = (uint8_t*) xx1_address;


float get_xx1_temperature(void) {
    uint8_t raw_temp = *xx1;

    if(raw_temp * 0x80 != 0) {
        /* Error flag set */
        return NAN;
    }
    /* No error */
    return (raw_temp + xx1_offset) * xx1_scale;
}
```